# Higher order functions in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, higher-order-functions

I have these two functions:

```
 def replaceValue(value: String): String =
    if (value.startsWith(":")) value.replaceFirst(":", "/") else value

  def getData(value: String): String = {
    val res = replaceValue(value).replace("-", ":")
    val res1    = res.lastIndexOf(":")
    if (res1 != -1) res.substring(0,3)
    else res.concat("-")
  }
```

I want to convert them to higher order functions.

I have tried this so far.
What would be the higher order function for it?

```
  def getData = (value: String) => {
    val res = replaceValue(value).replace("-", ":")
    val res1    = res.lastIndexOf(":")
    if (res1 != -1) res.substring(0,3)
    else res.concat("-")
  }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by _high order function_? Do you want a function that creates the `getData` function?

Comment: Yes. By any means i want to avoid this if else conditions like:
def getData =  (f: String => String, value: String)

and then i can pass either substring or concat.

I want this method to be as precise as possible @TomerShetah

Comment: Or  def getData(value: String) : String => String

Comment: So there is  no better way to write this function ?

Comment: @EatPayBong I think you should figure out what problem you are trying to solve instead of just trying to write a HOF

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
def getDataImpl(f: String => String)(value: String): String = {
    f(value)
}

def getDataSubstring: String => String = getDataImpl(_.substring(0,3))
def getDataConcat: String => String = getDataImpl(_.concat("-"))

def getData(value: String): String = {
    val replaced = replaceValue(value).replace("-", ":")
    if (replaced.contains(":")) {
        getDataConcat(replaced)
    } else {
        getDataSubstring(replaced)
    }
}
```

Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pLKthJcKRRq1lbq5ladkQQ).

Comment: in my opinion this is just an unnecessary function wrapping, getDataImpl serves no purpose

Comment: I agree that in this example it doesn't add much. But in more complicated cases you would like to apply a mutual behaviour in `getDataImpl`, and then it does help. Don't forget that this is just a minimal example, it can represent a much more complicated flow.